# showing 1-n relations in JSF

Tags: jsf

I want to place a table on my page. I have two tables in my database for example users and locations. Every location has more than one user. I want to list these locations and show the users who live in these locations.

---

Los Angeles

1. John Locke
2. Dr. Jack
3. Mr. Eco

Like the below image, could someone do this in JSF?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't see the image. Maybe just link to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use RichFaces to do such thing:

```
<h:form>
<rich:dataList var="city" value="#{myBean.allCity}">
    <h:outputText value="#{city.name}" ></h:outputText>
    <rich:dataList var="user" value="#{city.users}">
         <h:outputText value="#{user.name}" ></h:outputText>
    </rich:dataList>
</rich:dataList>
</h:form>
```

Where allCity - list of the City, and every City has list of the user inside.

See http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/dataLists.jsf?c=dataList&tab=usage for example.

Backing bean:

**myBean:**

```
public class MyBean(){
   private ArrayList<City> allCity= new ArrayList<City>();

   @PostConstruct
   public void init(){
     //fill Array list
   }

    public ArrayList<City> getAllCity() {
     return allCity;
    }      

}
```

**City:**

```
public class City{
   private ArrayList<User> users= new ArrayList<User>();

   public City( ArrayList<User> users){
     this.users = users;
     // you can get data from database in myBean, and pass it hear with cinstructor;
   }

   public ArrayList<User> getUsers() {
     return allCity;
   }     
}
```

**User**

```
public class User{
  private String name;

  //constructor and others fields;

  public String getName(){
     return name;
  }
}
```

Only MyBean you register as backing-bean. I show you only base structure of class, how you fill it with data is you choice.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did it as you said and everything is ok.

Comment: I see you new hear, if you accept answer click on button \/. You should do this in all you questions. :)